# Select a list of entries in Column A where column B = 'value'. Then select all entries where column A is one of the list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table that has entries like:

```
RuleID Symbol    
1      OR    
1      123   
1      363    

2      AND    
2      847   
2      287   

3      AND    
3      NOT   
3      234   
3      867   

4      NOT    
4      995
```

The result should be:

```
3      AND    
3      NOT   
3      234   
3      867 

4      NOT    
4      995
```

Symbol='NOT' corresponds to RuleID='3' and RuleID='4'. I want to

```
select * in table where RuleID = '3' or '4'
```

How can I do this with SQL server?

Comment: select * from table where RuleID  in('3' , '4' )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it using Joins which is generally faster than using the IN clause

```
SELECT T.* 
from table T INNER JOIN 
( SELECT Distinct RuleID 
  FROM table 
  WHERE SYMBOL = 'not' 
) A
ON A.RuleID = T.RuleID
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use `in` for that. For example:

Select * from table WHERE RULEID in (select RULEID from table where SYMBOL = 'not')